# In Gin-Rummy, when not to Knock?

Tags: gin-rummy

In [Gin-Rummy](https://www.pagat.com/rummy/ginrummy.html), besides several exceptions, in most rounds the best move is to Knock as soon as possible.  What are those exceptions? When it is better to go for Gin / Undercut?

While this question generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, I presume that some guidelines are a consensus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Rummy-Talk: When to Knock, Play for Gin, or Underknock](http://rummytalk.com/when-to-knock-play-for-gin-or-underknock/)

> Knock, under most conditions, should be utilized at the first opportunity, with a few
>   exceptions:
>
> 1. When the odds are in favor of your going out in a game, or obtaining
>      enough score to catch up to your opponent.
> 2. When it is a reasonable
>      assumption on your part that you stand to be underknocked by laying
>      off his cards.
> 3. When you know that your opponent is not in a position
>      to knock his hand
> 4. When you have your opponent’s hand dead.
> 5. When your hand has the characteristics of a gin hand.